# Academic papers on GPU password cracking?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

Are there any scientific papers or publications on GPU password cracking?

Comment: See our [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00114.pdf) on attacks and security techniques for GPUs. It reviews security vulnerabilities of GPUs along with their countermeasures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure a lot of article can be found on the web giving a clear explanation on how to setup a GPU password cracking system, but if you are looking for an academic paper, you can take a look at those reports :

- http://staff.science.uva.nl/~delaat/rp/2010-2011/p11/report.pdf
- http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM100812.pdf
- http://mnsu.academia.edu/KhaiTran/Papers/1559507/GPU_-_accelerated_WPA_PSK_cracking_solutions

I think this blog post (not an academic paper, I admit), is quite complex and very interesting to read : http://mytechencounters.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/gpu-password-cracking-crack-a-windows-password-using-a-graphic-card/

You can also give a look at the [Google Scholar page](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=academic%20paper%20gpu%20cracking) that will list some result regarding your research.

Comment: I just did. You were talking about the .fr link right?